# Why do closed questions and downvoted answers appear in search results?

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

I have been searching for stuff on stack exchange sites for some time now and I have notices a problem. Whenever I search for something, I always find spam answers that are closed or that are "on hold" I find this really annoying because these questions get closed for a reason and they are errelevent to my question. Why do closed question still end up on search pages?

Comment: Why not? As long as it's not deleted, it means it still got *some* value, even if basically wrong/unhelpful. Spam gets deleted and you won't find it in search results, believe me.

Comment: You can apply `isclosed:no` to your search, if you want to filter them out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Because usually closed questions are duplicates or stuff that can't be answered

Comment: @AndyTechGuy A great reason to have dupes appear in search results is the fact that not everyone searches on the same keywords. And dupes have a link to an answered question, so with only an extra click, you'll find help with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they haven't been deleted.

In theory, questions that are on hold or closed are in a temporary state.

From that state, they should either be edited and reopened, or deleted.

Unless they're upvoted duplicates, in which case they're retained as SEO fodder.

In practice, on many SE sites, deletion & reopening doesn't happen anywhere near as often as it should, so there's a lot of closed question left lying around, that shouldn't be there.